# What's the best way to duplicate Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, frontend

So I've developed the front-end for a database. The controller has all 7 standard actions + a few more. The view is composed of index, edit, new,...etc. Now I need to make 3 more of these and the only thing different about them is realistically one line as I'm making a SQL call to some table to fetch/edit info for every controller action and the only thing different is the table name for each database view. What's a good way of doing this without just copying the same code 3 times over and changing one variable?

Example of controller:

```
server = windows_prod

def index
  @servers = connection.exec_query("SELECT [COL1]...[COLN] FROM #{server}")
end
```

the rest of the actions are along these lines, the only thing chaging would be the server assignment at the top.

Comment: Can you please post an example of a controller? Depending on your needs and how your controller look like, there are Gems like [make_resourceful](https://github.com/hcatlin/make_resourceful) that might help you.

Comment: Is there any reason you re not using ActiveRecord to fetch the data from the database?

Comment: I'm with Leito! This degree of coupling between the controller and the DB gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Comment: I realize it's less than ideal, but my senior devs specifically wanted it this way.

Comment: Just turn the fragment into a method and pass the "variables" as arguments.

Comment: @Turk Your "senior devs" are scary then; at the *very* least this should be isolated in a service class/object. Then you'd just pass the server into a service method, and you're done. A single test suite for the service, and trivial action testing with a mocked service.

Comment: Just curious, how exactly would I use ActiveRecord to fetch from an external db? Currently, I have the db configured in a database.yml file and then I connect to it with some functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider placing the reusable controller logic into a Mixin.  This would look something like:

```
module ReusableControllerLogic

  def index
    @servers = connection.exec_query("SELECT [COL1]...[COLN] FROM #{server}")
  end

  def show
    # Blah
  end
end
```

Now, you can use this Mixin on any Controller that defines a method named `server`.  This method should return the desired name of the server:

```
class AwesomeController < ApplicationController
  include ReusableControllerLogic

  private
  def server
    "awesome"
  end
end
```